# PHP: program in php

Tags: php

Good what I want to achieve is to make a program in php using the mt_rand () method, when I remove that method a 3 has to stop executing but I don't get it, this is what I have:

```
<?php

$randomnumbers = mt_rand();
$stopnumber = 3;

while($randomnumbers != $stopnumber){
        echo $randomnumbers;
}

?>
```

what I want to achieve is this, when the series is a 3 it stops running and stops.

I attach a photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq9o9.jpg

Comment: mt_rand without params can return a number from 0 to 2147483647, and you're not incrementing or changing stopnumber nor calling mt_rand again so the while loop is infinite

Comment: So you want to stop if last number is `3`

Comment: mt_rand creates one number - you should first set interval - for example from 0 to 10, next - generate in inside "while" - it did code for you check out my answer

Comment: or do all in the while loop https://3v4l.org/2rAjL and echo the 3 after

Comment: could also use a generator if your feeling bored https://3v4l.org/HEgqo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$stopnumber = 3;
$randomnumbers = mt_rand(0,10);

while($randomnumbers != $stopnumber){
        echo $randomnumbers . ' ';
        $randomnumbers = mt_rand(0,10); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it took a while and I could not find the solution thank you very much

Comment: i happy to help, you can mark my question as answer